# Is it possible to set up a wifi router with no internet?

Tags: router, wifi

Is it possible to use a standard Linksys-type router and set up an internet-free wireless network?   Example:

- Devices can see "My Network" and connect to it.
- While connected, calls to the internet will obviously not work, because there is no internet.  But calls to a local IP like 192.168.0.101 would work and could be answered by a Raspberry PI running Apache

My ultimate goal is let several Raspberry PIs in a room talk to each other, though I'd like the entire network of them to be accessible from a local Android Tablet.  The various PIs would basically work like RESTful webservers, listening for HTTP GET/POST calls from the tablet or from a sibling Pi.

Comment: `Is it possible to use a standard Linksys-type router and set up an internet-free wireless network?` - Yes.

Comment: yes just don't connect the router to the internet

Comment: @Mike I didn't think it'd be that simple, but that makes sense.  I guess I wasn't expecting the router to function at all with no internet.

Comment: @Anthony yep it'll work.. funny how the simplest solution is usually the best :)

Comment: It is that simple. A Wireless router functions as 3 distinct devices: A Wireless Access Point (Layer 2), an Ethernet switch (Layer 2) and a Router (Layer 3). There's no requirement that you use the routing function. It can operate perfectly normally as just a WAP and a switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to do this by simply not connecting your router to the internet.

Comment: Thanks all - taking baby steps towards my goal.  Appreciate it!